# ABAP Real Life Program using guidelines

Tags: abap, design-guidelines

In [ABAP Guidelines](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=ABENABAP_PGL.htm) is mencioned the package SABAP_DEMOS_CAR_RENTAL with Objects that are used the Guidelines, but I looking for an SAP program using this guidelines.

In general the  SAP programs are so bigger and I get lost in the source code, so anyone know some program that are easy to identify the use of Guidelines?

Thank you

Comment: The package is not for the guidelines. It's not shown in the ABAP guidelines, but in the [ABAP Objects Overview](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_objects_oview.htm). Of course, probably, programs in this package are well written and complies the guidelines, but not certain. That said, do you want to learn the syntax of ABAP Objects (considering that you already know Object Oriented Programming OOP), or to learn the best practices for OOP? (there's nothing specific to ABAP Objects) Learning OOP = use the recommended OO Design Patterns.

Comment: This package is mentioned on [guidelines](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennames_repos_obj_guidl.htm)  too. What I want is to see an SAP Program using OO Design Patterns. Today I found Partner Transaction (BP), but it's very confusing, and appear to use OO only for dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to learn ABAP Object. If so, you can try this link for example. It's easier to practicing than just reading

http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ABAP/OOP/Example2.htm

This site also contains lots of other stuff

Regards,
Binh